# React jest - Verify the state has been changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using jest in order to test my components.

I want to test a specific method that I know that the method change the state.

```
it('should calculate width of publisher menu', () => {
    window.innerWidth = 3000
    const publisherContainer = new PubContainer(props)
    console.log(publisherContainer.state.maxVisibleTabs) // maxVisibleTabs is 1
    publisherContainer.resize() // here i'm using setState({maxVisibleTabs : 10})
    console.log(publisherContainer.state.maxVisibleTabs) // maxVisibleTabs is 1
})
```

I would like to check that resize actually did the setState to 10, but the the value `1` is still there.

I know that setState is async and that the state does not mutate immediately but do I have any elegant\workaround to solve this?

Comment: Can you add the code you're trying to test - there's a few ways to do this

Comment: @DarrenSweeney , resize method only does the setState. I just wanted to check whether the state has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually three ways to deal with asynchronous code in tests:

1. Make the asynchronous code synchronous somehow. Probably not an option here.
2. Poll the system under test until you get the right result or timeout.
3. Create a mechanism in your production code that will allow the test to know that something happened - for example, add an event mechanism, so that code from outside the component can register to state changes. Then the test code can register for them and wait for the event to come.

Unfortunately, Jest doesn't come with a polling mechanism built-in, but you can probably write something simple yourself using a `setTimeout` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) with jest, it makes testing react components a lot easier. It comes with an [update](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) function that solves this problem.